# Angle between a line and a circle that it goes though

Tags: derivatives, circles

I just solved a task regarding the angle under which a certain line goes through a circle. The line naturally has two common points with the circle. It seems that the angle between them is the same in both point A and B. Intuitively it seems that's the case for every chosen circle and line going through. Is it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Draw a line perpendicular to your line through the center of the circle. Then your line and it's intersection with the circle is symmetric w.r.t to that radius. There are some exceptional cases (your line is a diameter) but these are easy to handle.

Comment: What about hyperbole and parabola? Are the two angles always the same as well?

Comment: @user3476528 no, not in general. These do not have that many symmetries as the circle.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thank you for your help :)